# Comparing measurements obtained from >2 devices (Bland-Altman, Tukey mean difference plot)

Tags: data-visualization, spss, agreement-statistics, method-comparison, bland-altman-plot

I would like to **compare different measurements in regard to agreement**. Quite often this is done **using a Bland-Altman plot** (also called **Tukey mean difference** plot) in medical literature.

What I would like to do is **compare more than 2 devices** (namely, 4 devices). 3 of the devices are commercially available and one has been newly developed. I am eager to find out how well the newly developed device performs compared to the other ones. None of the commercially available devices can be considered a "gold standard". **What would be the best way to do so?**

I am currently **considering the following two options** (but I am open to any other solutions):

1. Calculating a new variable "commercially_available" that is the mean of all commercially available devices and then plot the mean of the "commercially_available" and the new device  vs. the difference between the "commercially_available" and the new device. (So basically, **combining the measurements obtained be the commercially available devices into one measurement using the MEAN function**)
2. **Creating three different plots**, each comparing one commercially available device with the newly developed device.

Comment: What is your data (is it continuous or discrete)? What do you mean by *agreement*? The second question is very important, since if you mean by agreement that $x = y$ it is very different then if you mean $|x - y| \leq \varepsilon$ and those two definitions could lead to totally different results (agreement of 0% vs 100% in some cases).

Comment: All data is continuous in this case. Ideally, agreement would be x=y, but since all devices incur an error of measurement, I would be interested in |x-y|

Comment: In continuous case $P(X = x) = 0$, so defining agreement as $x=y$ makes no sens.

Comment: I am trying to clarify it: It's about measuring the concentration of a substance in blood using different devices. Any concentration is possible, therefore data is continous. Now, if I draw a blood sample and measure the concentration using 4 different devices, I (ideally) obtain 4 measurement values that are exactly the same. Now, this is very unlikely to happen (as none of the devices is "totally accurate" and each device includes a certain error). I am interested to know how accurately the newly developed device measures the concentration.